# When should I plant out a peach sapling?

Tags: fruit-trees, transplanting, peaches

When is the best time to plant out a peach sapling?

I have been trying my hand at growing cuttings from peach tree prunings, and eventually(*) have one that is almost big enough to plant out. I'll wait until after the coming winter, but when is the ideal time? Presumably spring?  Should I plant it out before the leaves come out, or after?

(*) Two attempts. First mistake was the wrong time of the year. Also I've tended to use branches that are too thin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't plant the sapling when the ground is frozen or if it is too cold outside. The conditions would be too harsh for it to survive on its own. The ideal time would be after the ground has cleared of ice, when spring just sets in.

I can't talk from winter/ice experience, but I planted my peach sapling (about 1.5 ft tall; no leaves, only buds) out last year in late December in San Diego, when the temperature was around 10-15 C (50-60 F), no frost/ice/snow. By mid February, the plant sprouted leaves and by mid March, it had at least 6 peaches growing (which, I did *not* expect from a tree this young!). Now, it's about 3 feet tall and fully covered with leaves. The pic below is from mid March.

[image]

So it's more about how harsh/unwelcoming the conditions are outside than if the leaves have come out/not.

Comment: Yes it is about that size (1.5ft give or take). For the buds, I was thinking of the advice given for taking cuttings: just before the buds open. So pretty much early/mid spring - probably the same time I plant store-bought pepper plants out. If only we had a crystal ball to know when the last frost is indeed the last frost!